# Is the code inside a Q_ASSERT statement executed in release mode?

Tags: c++, qt, assert

By design, an `Q_ASSERT` will not cause an application to fail in release mode. My question is does the code inside a `Q_ASSERT` still run in release mode?

```
bool assertTest()
{
    int x = 0;
    Q_ASSERT(++x);
    return x == 1;
}
```

Will `assertTest()` return a different value in release mode than it does in debug mode?

Comment: How is `Q_ASSERT` defined?

Comment: rename `bool assertTest()` to `int main()` and test it yourself.

Comment: @Casey - unfortunately, setting up a Qt project isn't quite as trivial as just changing that function name. It still would not take a great amount of time, surely, and I will do so if nobody who already knows the answer appears.

Comment: @Cory I'm not sure what you mean by set up a Qt project, but all you have to do to test this is include the `QtGlobal` header.

Comment: @DavidBrown - I was under the impression, apparently mistakably, that a Qt project .pro file would also be required.

Comment: @CoryKlein, you can generate `.pro` given sources in the separate dir with `qmake -project` command in that dir

Comment: It would certainly take less time to test this than to post a question. Here: I'll time it: 1:31 to start QtCreator, make new console project, paste in your code, hit control-R to build and run it.

Comment: @Casey - Well, if I didn't post the question I wouldn't have the code, so you'd have to include the time, albeit small, spent writing the code as well. Regardless, I posted this question mainly with the intent of improving this wiki, in an effort to save others from having to write a test project in order to find the answer to their question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt documentation [states](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#Q_ASSERT) that

> Q_ASSERT does nothing if QT_NO_DEBUG was defined during compilation.

Additionally, it [warns](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/debug.html) that `Q_ASSERT` condition will not be executed, if asserts are disabled.

> `Q_ASSERT()`, `Q_ASSERT_X()`, and `Q_CHECK_PTR()` expand to nothing if
>   `QT_NO_DEBUG` is defined during compilation. *For this reason, the
>   arguments to these macro should not have any side-effects*. Here is an
>   incorrect usage of `Q_CHECK_PTR()`:
>
> ```
> char *alloc(int size) 
> {
>     char *ptr;
>     Q_CHECK_PTR(ptr = new char[size]);  // WRONG
>     return ptr; 
> }
> ```

Comment: I've been trying to find the documentation that states unequivocally that `QT_NO_DEBUG` is defined when qmake is passed `CONFIG += debug`.  I can't.

Comment: @cmannett85, I also couldn't find, but the point of question is not about whether asserts enabled in release, but if condition is executed if asserts are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Side effects within asserted expressions are almost always an error. They should be flagged during competent code review and/or when using a static analysis tool. **It doesn't matter precisely what Q_ASSERT does, it's bad to depend on it anyway** - even if you knew what it does.